# Do you understand why the Outputs of my YOLOV4 model has this shape?

Tags: python, machine-learning, training-data, yolov4

I have a question.
I trained a YOLOV4 model for face detection and when i tried to look at the output on Neutron i found that the Bounding Box shape is [1,1,1] and Feature has the shape of [1,1,4] is there something wrong that i did ?

Thank you![Neutron]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnj1h.png

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

This is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64228004/6299772).
But basically it's like this:

(1,1,4) is the result for the bounding boxes. The first number 1 is according to your image fed into the model. As you have only one object then the output is 1 for the second number. Furthermore, YOLO configuration for bounding boxes are (x_center,y_center,width,height), which are the 4 positions.

(1,1,1) will be the same, but now 1 is for the label of the class you choose.

Comment: If there is already an answer in Stack Overflow, there is no point in answering again.

Comment: It has been done thousands of times...

Comment: And? That is irrelevant.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy i said this because i have this error that i don't understand, so if you can help : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Size of bounding box dimension 2 is not 4. Got 1 in shape [1, 2535, 1]